setTimeout() not available in mujs
Help, I'm trying to setup my environment to do a Hello World.
 1 #!/usr/bin/env mujs                                                             
 2                                                                                 
 3 console.log("Hello!");                                                          
 4 setTimeout(console.log, 2000);  // 2s

$ nano lqlq.js && ./lqlq.js 
Hello!
ReferenceError: 'setTimeout' is not defined
        at ./lqlq.js:4

That particular interpreter prides itself in being standard-compliant

There are no non-standard extensions
source

but I can't see how a basic sleep() can be non-standard.
extra/mujs 1.3.5-1 [installed]
    An embeddable Javascript interpreter in C

$ uname -r
6.10.4-arch2-1


setTimeout() is not part of JavaScript. It was a browser API originally (and still is), and Node supports it. If this interpreter of yours is embedded in a C context, you could probably write your own timer mechanism and provide it to the runtime.

setTimeout is not part of JS - it's host-provided. It's defined by the HTML standard and also adopted by Node.JS. So, their claim to have no non-standard stuff holds water.

I can't see setTimeout in the ES5 spec: https://es5.github.io/spec.html

I like this question.  It just happens to be based on a false assumption.  But clearing up what's part of the language and what's part of the platform / environment seems like a useful answer.  I don't think you're the only one to wonder about what's included with JavaScript.  I upvoted.

Please don't edit your question to add "thank you" or an answer. You can post an answer to your own question if you want.

@jabaa your rollback was questionable.  It seemed to add the extra information that the asker understood that setTimeout was part of node.js, but perhaps was still looking for a solution for mujs.  I understand that the "thank you" was extra though.

@Wyck OP should add the edit as an answer and accept it.  Unless they rephrase the whole question (as there's no existing answers) to be "it's part of node, how do I make it part of mujs".   Also, with the edit there's no question.  (edit: though, on review, there's no actual question as it stands...)

@Wyck The edit changes the question. That would be okay, since the question isn't answered, but wouldn't it be better to ask a new question? The first question was, why mujs doesn't support setTimeout. The new question was , how to get the function from Nodejs.

Nitpick: "That particular interpreter prides itself in being standard-compliant" and "There are no non-standard extensions" don't mean the same. You can have an interpreter that is not standard compliant and that does not contain non-stanard extensions. It guarantees that every code written in mujs works in a standard-compliant interpreter, but it doesn't guarantee the other direction.

@fdomn-m it did not answer the question, but attempted to reduce the scope of the question - Given the extra information, the question could be less about "how can it be non standard" and more about "how can I do setTimeout in mujs".  But the question is asked from a valid perspective.  I think questions lose something when the original motivation is removed.  I agree that any misunderstanding becomes a two-part answer: a) you can't do that b) here's what you do instead.  A wiser person may have had foresight to ask two questions, but it's fine if they did not, in my opinion. I still like it.

I think, that's the problem when a question doesn't contain an explicit, specific question. It's not clear what the OP actually asks. You can interpret a different question as others. IMO, this question falls under Why is "Can someone help me?" not a useful question?

(edit: though, on review, there's no actual question as it stands...) But @jabaa deleted the question part, which was (although not articulated with a question mark) "Now I only need to convince mujs to see it."  The asker explained the misunderstanding "how (can) ... be non-standard" and asked for the solution: needing setTimeout.

@Wyck "as it stands" is.. as it stands now - which is with the rollback- which is the original question.   I was saying there was never an actual question here in the first place so OPs edit didn't change that by not adding a question!

setTimeout() is part of NodeJS. In order to use it, node's interpreter is needed.
#!/usr/bin/env node

